# How to classify values into groups (by their quadrants in the complex plane)?

Tags: matlab, classification

Hi I have a 4x4 double matrix

```
 1+2i   2-1i  -3-2i  -1+4i

 3-1i  -3+2i   1-3i  -1-3i   

 4+3i   3+5i   1-2i  -1-4i  

 4+2i  -5-2i   2+3i   2-1i
```

How do I group them into separate groups in the 1+1i, 1-1i, -1+1i, -1-1i category in MATLAB?

E.g. 1+1i group: 1+2i, 4+3i, 3+5i, 4+2i, 2+3i
     1-1i group: 2-1i, 3-1i, 1-3i, 1-2i, 2-1i
    -1+1i group: -1+4i, -3+2i
    -1-1i group: -3-2i, -1-3i, -1-4i, -5-2i

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
% example matrix
Z = [ 1+2i   2-1i  -3-2i  -1+4i ;
      3-1i  -3+2i   1-3i  -1-3i ; 
      4+3i   3+5i   1-2i  -1-4i ; 
      4+2i  -5-2i   2+3i   2-1i ]
```

---

**Brute force approach, if you don't care about the order of the groups:**

```
classification = ceil( angle(Z)*4/(2*pi) ) + 2

quadrant1 = Z(classification == 3)
quadrant2 = Z(classification == 4)
quadrant3 = Z(classification == 1)
quadrant4 = Z(classification == 2)
```

change the order as desired. You can of course also use the loop/cellfun from below.

---

**Or with automatic order:**

*Be aware that I have chosen a meaningful order according to the gaussian complex plane, because the one proposed by you does not make sense in terms of mathematics/phyisics.*

```
classification = ceil( angle(Z)*4/(2*pi) );
classification(classification < 1) = classification(classification < 1) + 4;
for ii = 1:4;
    quadrant{ii,:} = Z(classification == ii);
end
```

or substitute the loop with:

```
quadrant = cellfun(@(x) Z(classification == x), num2cell(1:4),'Uni',0)'
```

returns a cell array with 4 cells, one for every quadrant in the right order containing all the according complex numbers:

```
>> quadrant{:}

ans =

   1.0000 + 2.0000i
   4.0000 + 3.0000i
   4.0000 + 2.0000i
   3.0000 + 5.0000i
   2.0000 + 3.0000i


ans =

  -3.0000 + 2.0000i
  -1.0000 + 4.0000i


ans =

  -5.0000 - 2.0000i
  -3.0000 - 2.0000i
  -1.0000 - 3.0000i
  -1.0000 - 4.0000i


ans =

   3.0000 - 1.0000i
   2.0000 - 1.0000i
   1.0000 - 3.0000i
   1.0000 - 2.0000i
   2.0000 - 1.0000i
```

---

[Don't punch me Rody](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21137395/2605073) - but then I would rather write it as follows:

```
Im = imag(Z) >= 0;
Re = real(Z) >= 0;

quadrant = {
    Z(  Re &  Im)
    Z( ~Re &  Im)
    Z( ~Re & ~Im)
    Z(  Re & ~Im)
};
```

... because I intended to avoid all these 8 logical comparisons. Is it really faster?

Comment: Well, `angle` involves an `atan`, and is not built-in. Using `cellfun` with an anonymous function can be slow. You're right that your implementation should be even faster :) But my notation is closer to how you'd write things in a mathematical context, improving readability by self-documentation, but the benefits of that can be debated as they are more a matter of taste.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis That's correct, your notation could be copied from a mathematical formulary with some curly brackets around. :p The thing is you're doing 8 times, what my brute force approach (similar to yours) is just doing 4 times, and there is no additional `&` operation. I don't know if there are any differences between the operators `<,>,==,&` performance wise, but you seem to have much more relational operations. +1 anyway for your solution, it's really just a matter of taste ;)

Answer (score 3):

Fastest and most intuitive IMHO:

```
Im = imag(Z);
Re = real(Z);

quadrant = {
    Z(Im >  0 & Re >  0)
    Z(Im >  0 & Re <= 0)
    Z(Im <= 0 & Re >  0)
    Z(Im <= 0 & Re <= 0)
};
```